# Math with analog input values coming out wrong

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, analogread

Im getting stuck in a while loop because Im having trouble running a calculation on some sensor values. When I read my four sensors values and compare the ratio of the first two to the second two, I keep getting 0.00, no matter what the values are. Here's my code:

```
while ( ( (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright) <= 0.8 ) || ( (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright) > 1.2) ) {
    if (backleft + backright > frontleft + frontright) {
      myStepper2.step(10);
    }
    if (backleft + backright < frontleft + frontright) {
      myStepper2.step(-10);
    }
    int backleft = analogRead(A0);
    int backright = analogRead(A1);
    int frontleft = analogRead(A2);
    int frontright = analogRead(A3);   

    Serial.print("Backleft Reading: ");
    Serial.println(backleft);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("BackRight Reading: ");
    Serial.println(backright);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("Frontleft Reading: ");
    Serial.println(frontleft);
    Serial.print("\n");
    Serial.print("Frontright Reading: ");
    Serial.println(frontright);
    Serial.print("\n");
    float ratio = (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright);
    float math = (5 + 6) / (4 + 5);
    Serial.print("Math: ");
    Serial.println(math);
    Serial.print("Ratio: ");
    Serial.println(ratio);
    Serial.print("\n");
    delay(500);

  }
```

Im getting values for my sensors (backleft, backright, frontleft, frontright), but 'ratio' always comes out 0.00. Because of that, Im getting trapped in the loop I believe. What's going on here?

Also, just to check, I added 'math' float as that quick calculation, but I'm getting a value of 1.00 in Serial Monitor. Why? It should be 1.222.

Answer (score 1):

Read this: [Integer arithmetic and overflow](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12146).

```
float math = (5 + 6) / (4 + 5);
Serial.print("Math: ");
Serial.println(math);
```

The compiler is treating your expression (the RH side of the "=" sign) as **integers**. Thus it is working out:

```
11 / 9 = 1
```

Then you assign that `1` to a float. Too late to make it a float! It is already truncated.

Try:

```
float math = float (5 + 6) / float (4 + 5);
Serial.print("Math: ");
Serial.println(math, 4);  // 4 decimal places
```

You get:

```
Math: 1.2222
```

---

This also looks wrong:

```
while ( ( (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright) <= 0.8 ) || ( (frontleft + frontright) / (backleft + backright) > 1.2) ) {
    if (backleft + backright > frontleft + frontright) {
      myStepper2.step(10);
    }
    if (backleft + backright < frontleft + frontright) {
      myStepper2.step(-10);
    }
    int backleft = analogRead(A0);
    int backright = analogRead(A1);
    int frontleft = analogRead(A2);
    int frontright = analogRead(A3);
```

How many `backleft` variables do you have? The one in the `while` instruction will **not** be the one you are doing the analogRead on. It doesn't "forward read" variables. I bet you have a different `frontleft` / `backleft` etc. set of variables declared earlier. These will **not** be updated inside the loop.

(To make them get updated drop the word `int` from inside the loop).